# rubymine debug rspec Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rspec, rubymine

i setup a rails project and i cant get rspec to run in rubymine. Here are my testing gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'faker'
end
```

and here is my error message

```
/Users/dude/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/dude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myproject/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --port 53125 --dispatcher-port 53126 -- /Users/dude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myproject/bin/rspec /Users/dude/Code/myproject/spec/models/instagram_user_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --example InstagramUser --require /Applications/RubyMine.app/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/rspec3_formatter.rb
Testing started at 9:03 PM ...
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.23.beta1, debase 0.0.9) listens on 127.0.0.1:53125
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter
    /Users/dude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myproject/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1025:in `require'
    .......
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a spec in RubyMine results in "cannot load such file -- teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter (LoadError)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525945/running-a-spec-in-rubymine-results-in-cannot-load-such-file-teamcity-spec-ru)

Comment: i already tried that:$ spring stop
Spring is not running

Comment: rspec works in my other rubymine projects just not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i reinstalled rubymine and now the builtin rspec debugger works fine.